# iOS - Delete app before update through iTunesConnect / Xcode

Tags: app-store-connect, updating

Hi everyone,

Is it possible to delete an app from users'devices before updating it through iTunes Connect ?

I mean, I've got the following problem :
When I change the data model on my app ( using Core Data ) and release a new build on iTunes Connect, the app crashes on my testers'devices. It is the same for me, when I build my app after changing the data model, it crashes unless I delete the app from my device first.

The only thing I can do for now is telling my user to delete the app before installing the new version. That's a bit annoying..
Do you have a solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to automatically delete an app from the users device before installing the new version through iTunes connect.

Regarding your Core Data problem you should look into migration. Most of the time a "lightweight migration" is enough to prevent the updated version from crashing.

The following links might be helpful:

- [Apple documentation on Core Data migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH1-SW1)
- [Apple documentation on lightweight migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1)